# Removing padding only Bootstrap nav bar while keeping it everywhere else

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the setting for all elements in the body set to padding: 10px. I want to remove the padding setting for the navbar and set it to 0px so that it is flush against the edges but I don't know how to. I have tried to just add padding: 0px to .navbar-custom but it didn't do anything Here is my code:

```
            <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Jump to...</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-list-ul"></i>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i>
                        </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#smartphone">Item 1</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#data">Item 2</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#bam">Item 3</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#sim">Item 4</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #0e47b0;
    width: 100% !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: none !important;
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .fa-x {
    display: none !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .fa-list-ul {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0px !important;
    border: none !important;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand, .navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.nav-link, .nav-link:hover, .nav-link:visited, .nav-link:focus, .nav-link:active {
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5%;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: what is wrong by adding `p-0` to the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the navbar is part of the body content it will always be constrained to the styles applied, I would recommend making a container style div after the navbar to put the padding on that will open just after the navbar and close before the closing body tag. this way the styles that you want for your content can still be applied effectively skipping putting them on the navbar as well.

Comment: That's really smart I failed to think of that. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help! We've all been there don't worry!

Comment: way to complicated. The simple solution would be to make use of `specificty-weight` or apply the style to all element inside the body with exception of the navbar by using the `:not` selector

Comment: AH, How could I have forgot about `:not` thats a good solution, I'm unfamiliar with `specify-weight` but theres always a few good ways to do things